Migrating from mqtt Paho V1 to V2 reinitialise fails
On a reconnect, on_reconnect calls my reconnect function where I reinitialise the connection calling the reinitialise method of the client
mqttc.reinitialise(mqtt_clientID, clean_session=False, userdata=None) 

However, this triggers an error
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 1156, in reinitialise
    self.__init__(client_id, clean_session, userdata)  # type: ignore[misc]
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 772, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unsupported callback API version: version 2.0 added a callback_api_version, see docs/migrations.rst for details

Searching online for information I do find the migration information but nothing is mentioned about this method. Looking for the method, I only find info indicating I do the right thing.
I even tried this
mqttc.reinitialise(mqtt.CallbackAPIVersion.VERSION2, mqtt_clientID, clean_session=False, userdata=None)

but that triggers an error saying clean_session is mentioned twice.
What is wrong here? Where can I find information on the V2 reinitialise method?

There are a few open issues re this (one here and another) regarding this. Looks like a PR has been opened so hopefully this will be resolved soon.
